# php mysql using first between last row value difference

Tags: php

i display  data  use  Php . now  i want to   difference data table  first  row second column and last row second column . 
i add image . how do it ?
[image]

Comment: You'd do it by running a while loop and a foreach query however.. With no code being shown, I don't feel obliged to custom write this all out for you..

Comment: Please do show your approach. What codes you have tried.

Comment: Please add what you have to try..

Comment: Dear my friends . i have not idea code . i want  to result  distance.

Answer (score 0):

It will group by car_number and then get its max distance and min distance and will do difference of that and will give desired result in d_interval.
I hope this will help you!

```
SELECT t1.car_number, min(t1.distance) AS min_distance,
   max(t1.distance) AS max_distance,
   max(t1.distance) - min(t1.distance) AS d_interval
FROM table_name t1
GROUP BY t1.car_number
```